# Список в пользовательском Inspector

Tags: unity3d, list, unity3d-editor

Доброе время суток. Решил написать пользовательский Editor в Unity, при попытке отобразить

```
[SerializeField]
private List<FullActionState> _followingActions;
```

не показываются поля FullActionState в пользовательском Editor
А в Editor по умолчанию они видны

```
[Serializable]
public class FullActionState
{
    [SerializeField] private List<VariableState> variables;
    [SerializeField] private ActionState action;

    ...
}

[Serializable]
public class VariableState
{
    [SerializeField] private ChoiceNames.Condition _condition;
    [SerializeField] private ChoiceNames.PartName _part;
    [SerializeField] private ChoiceNames.IntVariable _intName;
    [SerializeField] private int _intValue;
    [SerializeField] private ChoiceNames.BoolVariable _boolName;
    [SerializeField] private bool _boolValue;

    ...
}
```

Для отображения списка я использовал

```
private SerializedProperty _followingActions;
private void OnEnable()
{
    _actionStateTest = target as ActionStateTest;
    _followingActions = serializedObject.FindProperty("_followingActions");
}

public override void OnInspectorGUI()
{
    serializedObject.Update();

    ditorGUILayout.PropertyField(_followingActions, true);

    serializedObject.ApplyModifiedProperties();
}
```

Должно быть так:

[image: Пример]

А сейчас

[image: Что имеем]

Comment: Атрибут `includeChildren` тут вааще не нужен, у меня даже случаев не было, когда я бы им воспользовался.

Comment: Я думал, что поможет, но разницы не заметил